# Send multiple values between two activities

Tags: java, android

Hi I´m just starting to learn how to use Android Studio. And I want to try to send the values of the choices the user makes from one activity to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data like this(this is from SecondActivity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

and than in ThirdActivity in onCreate method:

```
String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

Also, best practise is to have key "EXTRA_SESSION_ID" stored in public static variable so you have only one object

Comment: thank you for your answer but will this send multiple data? or just one cause this is pretty much what ive already done i think.

Comment: You can also send array or list or anything or you can define more intent.putExtrs("key01",value01), intent.putExtrs("key02",value02),

Comment: @effectivelvana I´ve tried implementing an array before without any success and I cant seem to find any solutions on the internet. Can you show me how to implement an array to store the values there?

Answer (score 1):

1.Change this to arraylist

```
 String[] mackor_names = {
            "Tonfisk Macka 30:-",
            "Skagen Macka 35:-",
            "Kyckling Macka 35:-",
            "Curryröra Macka 30:-",
            "Ost o Kalkon Macka 25:-",
            "Köttbulle Macka 25:-",
            "Falafel Macka 20:-"
        };






  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Tonfisk Macka 30:-");
    list.add("Skagen Macka 35:-"); ......
```

2.and then use

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("test",list);
```

3.and to get values

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
ArrayList<String> test = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

Comment: check the code now

Comment: list is pretty much same and what I am saying is use list instead of  string array and access element use list.get(1);

Comment: and add this array to list using this  line -   list.addAll(Arrays.asList(mackor_names));

Comment: now im getting error "cannot resolve symbol add"

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("VENUE_NAME", venueName);  
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

Insead of array you can use bundle